# pkgProblemResolver error when running Package Manager and updating 12.04

Tags: package-management, update-manager

Ubuntu 12.04 (Original Ubuntu version was 8.xx)

I have a message on the top bar that an error occurred and to run Package Manager.

I received the following message after running package manager:

```
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
```

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The following packages have been kept back:

```
evolution-common evolution-indicator evolution-plugins libnspr4 libnspr4:i386 libnspr4-0d
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

Newbie not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a problem involving a subset of the packages mentioned by the OP as follows:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get remove evolution-plugins
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Note sure if all of these steps were essential...

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nspr/+bug/1036794

Answer (score 0):

actually held packages can be get back with dist-upgrade

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then try again .

all the best.

Comment: desktop:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgradeReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnspr4 : Breaks: evolution-plugins (< 3.2.0-0ubuntu2) but 2.32.2-0ubuntu7 is to be installed
 libnspr4:i386 : Breaks: evolution-plugins (< 3.2.0-0ubuntu2) but 2.32.2-0ubuntu7 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: no change after running: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: @SLM answer edited .