# How to solve the pkgProblemResolver Error when upgrading to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my machine from 10.04 to 12.04 LTS but I get the following error. The same error occurs both in GUI and in terminal while doing `dist-upgrade`.

```
E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, 
  this may be caused by held packages.
```

I've tried to remove `libcv-dev` [as suggested in a comment to this blog post](http://bramp.net/blog/2012/04/failed-ubuntu-update/) but I don't have `libcv-dev` installed on my machine.

```
Package libcv-dev is not installed, so not removed
```

The pastebin link for the contents of `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` - http://pastebin.com/2GTRYNAY

How do I resolve the error and upgrade my machine to 12.04?

I've tried the solutions given in the following answer but it didn't work for me:

- [pkgProblemResolver error when running Package Manager and updating 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176189/pkgproblemresolver-error-when-running-package-manager-and-updating-12-04)

These are the terminal output of commands mentioned in those answers:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get remove evolution-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package evolution-plugins is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Hi @2er0 why don't you try using [GUI](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/ubuntu-10-04-12-04-upgrade-how-well-does-it-go)?

Comment: Same problem with the GUI, `E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, `

Comment: Then download iso file itself and while installing it will give you option for **upgrading**(installing without loosing any data).

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast reads of [UbuntuDesktop Upgrading](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#Upgrading) leads to idea that if your current installation has not version 10.04 LTS, then first you should upgrade to version 11.10, and next to 12.04 LTS.

This error looks like "unmet dependencies trouble".
Possible common solution is:
 1. Clean your sources lists and APT cache to leave only "genuine" Lucid sources.
 2. Upgrade your distribution.

Nice answers found here: [How do I upgrade from 10.04 or 11.10 to 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04?rq=1)

Comment: don't seem to work too. i had to backup my data and reinstall everything from scratch to 13.04 =(

Comment: that is a good logic you behave due to necessity of pkgProblemResolver is works alike an automatic resolution for the standard problems. So big changes better to resolve by your laborious hands skills ))

Answer (score -1):

How about...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: it doesnt work =(